# Javascript regular expressions. Getting the image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the variable below:

```
myvar = '<img src=".images/myimage.jpg"/>';
```

How can i get only the ".images/myimage.jpg" in a variable using regular expressions?

Comment: `"([^"]*)"` grab the string you want from index 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: why with regular expression?? you can do it using a substring. I can show you how do it if you want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for a regex which could be problematic.

```
var src = $(myvar).attr('src');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Under the hood, what happens is that the `$` function parses the HTML string to build a DOM element. You then retrieve its `src` attribute. The main benefit of this approach is that it is guaranteed to correctly parse the HTML.

Comment: @SalmanA You're right, having the Vanilla JS option as an answer might be good for other readers

Answer (score 4):

[Using Regular Expression is not the way to go, you should instead parse the HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You could use jQuery, to parse rapidly the HTML and then the `src` attribute. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29032515/2324107) is good and you should use that if jQuery is loaded.

**Nonetheless, if jQuery is not loaded, you should not load it just for that.**

If you want to get the `src` property or attribute (they are not the same) you can create a div and insert you HTML string into it. You will then be able to traverse the DOM and get the image `src`.

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = '<img src=".images/myimage.jpg"/>';
var img = wrapper.querySelector('img');

console.log(img.src);
console.log(img.getAttribute('src'));
```

Note that this snippet assume there will always be an image in the string. There is no condition to prevent error (but are easy to do).

[See it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/466jgppd/)